# How to repair an error "Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism in your device" in Python Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, pyperclip

I am using Pyperclip library in Python in Kivy UI, and I want to be able to copy a text by pressing a button, but it gives me this error message:

> 

```
pyperclip.PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error
```

My .py file is:

```
import kivy
import pyperclip
kivy.require("1.10.1")
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class Screen1(Screen):
    def copy_on_press(self):
        pyperclip.copy("text_which_should_be_copied")
class Copy(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name = "scr1"))
        return sm
    
app = Copy()
app.run()
```

My .kv file is:

```
<Screen1>:
    id: scr1
    orientation: "vertical"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "Background.png"

    Button:
        text: "Copy"
        on_press: scr1.copy_on_press()
```

Thanks for any answer.

I haven't found any informations which could solve my error.
I found similar errors, but their solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: So what sort of system are you running this code on?

Comment: I am using android 10 Lineage OS. The app is running in Pydroid 3.

Comment: Pyperclip apparently does not support Android at this time.  But Kivy has its own clipboard support - why aren't you using that, instead of a separate module?

Comment: I didn't know it. What is the name of that clipboard support?

Comment: Did you try [`Clipboard`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html?highlight=clipboard#module-kivy.core.clipboard) module?

Comment: Yes, I found it about 40 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I've found it. The .py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard
kivy.require("1.10.1")
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class Screen1(Screen):
    def copy_on_press(self): 
        Clipboard.copy("text_which_should_be_copied")
class Copy(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name = "scr1"))
        return sm
    
app = Copy()
app.run()
```

The .kv remains the same.